# Why am not able to fetch image in imageview from imageUrl?

Tags: java, android

I want to display an image in an `ImageView` which am fetching from a url which I have specified in function. The below is function where am trying to fetch image.

```
 public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src){
    try{

        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        return btmp;

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

The above function is returning `null`. The argument `src` "http://pyplyn.co/magento2pawan/a.jpg".

Please help me. Where I am going wrong....?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: No its not the duplicate.

Comment: LOL, yes, it is! ... check the logcat ...

Comment: Post your error stacktrace.

Comment: did you add the internet permission in your manifest? also, you might want to put the code into a async call....

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use libraries like Glide or Picasso rather than this when displaying Image from url

Comment: While this may be true, it doesn't explain what is wrong with the above code.